# Kinetic monte carlo simulation of a fcc lattice

Tags: c, montecarlo

I am currently trying to implement a research paper which requires me to make a fcc lattice in C. There are two atoms A and B and a vacancy, through which the migration should take place. The first nearest neighbours and the second nearest neighbours should be included, in the case of energy calculation. I am facing trouble in coding the neighbours of the fcc lattice. So, can someone please tell me how to code the neighbours. I am mentioning the code that I have written till now.

```
#define N 8
#define mcs 1000
#define SEED 5674599
#define Seed 526897

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int L[N][N][N],i,j,k,x,y,z,a,b,c,mc;
    double t=0;

    srand(SEED);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<N;k++)
            {
                if((float)rand()/RAND_MAX >= 0.5)
                {
                    L[i][j][k]= 1;  //Atom A    
                }
                else
                {
                    L[i][j][k]= -1;  //Atom B
                }       
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)//applying periodic boundary conditions
        {
            L[i][j][0]=L[i][j][N-1];
            L[i][0][k]=L[i][N-1][k];
            i=(i+N)%N;

            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {   
                L[0][j][k]=L[N-1][j][k];
                L[i][j][0]=L[i][j][N-1];    
                j=(j+N)%N;  

                for(k=0;k<N;k++)
                {
                    L[0][j][k]=L[N-1][j][k];
                    L[i][j][0]=L[i][j][N-1];
                    k=(k+N)%N;
                    L[0][0][0]=L[N-1][N-1][N-1];
                }
            }
        }

        srand(Seed);

        x=rand()%N;
        y=rand()%N;
        z=rand()%N;
        L[x][y][z]=0;   //vacant site
        //printf("L[%d][%d][%d]=%d",x,y,z,L[x][y][z]);


        fp=fopen("kmc.dat","w");
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<N;k++)
                {
                    L[i][j][k]=L[i][j][k];
                    fprintf(fp,"%d %d %d %d\n",i,j,k,L[i][j][k]);
                }
                fprintf(fp,"\n");
            }
            fprintf(fp,"\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);


        srand(time(NULL));  
        for(mc=0;mc<=1;mc++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                a=rand()%N;         
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    b=rand()%N;
                    for(k=0;k<N;k++)
                    {
                        c=rand()%N;
                        //printf("\nL[%d][%d][%d]=%d",a,b,c,L[a][b][c]);
                    }


                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Need to understand the FCC lattice first!! Chemistry along with coding knowledge is a rare combination I guess.

Comment: tell us more how you want to implement this neighbor, little bit more about its property. some link which we can follow up which you were using. Describe those things in your question

Comment: With *"applying periodic boundary conditions"* considering a sample cubic volume I would force the opposite sides to have identical distribution of A and B atoms, is that what you mean too? If that is the case, your code doesn't seem right, besides lines like `i=(i+N)%N;` serve no purpose, beeing those indeces already limited in the range [0,N).

Comment: It would be also useful if you could better clarify the structure you are trying to model, because at a first look, it seems more a primitive cubic system rather then a [face-centered cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system).